# How to fix (abort: http authorization required ERROR: Failed to clone) when built through hudson?

Tags: mercurial, hudson

I m building a simple project from hudson using mercurial repository URL. But its showing error in console as "abort: http authorization required ERROR: Failed to clone  http:\path\hudson_test".
As i m new to hudson tool please help me out for this.

Regards & thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's hudson telling you you need to provide the username and password for the repository you're accessing.  If it's HTTP you can put it right in the URL or in the `[auth]` section of the repository's `.hg/hgrc` file.  If it's a ssh-accessed repo you need to make the private key available likely using `ssh-agent`.